# how to use SignalR in swift 2.0 or later?

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, swift, signalr

I was in search for document or a sample that shows how to use SignalR in iOS with swift 2.0 or later , but didn't find any  until now so I am not able to provide any code here. I am looking for sample code. I am Using Xcode 7.2 Swift 2.1.1. Asp.net mvc 4 as Backend.Later I have found some libraries like [DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) and [adamhartford/SwiftR](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) but as a newbie with Swift I don't know which one Suits my Project(Creating a Chat Application that contains only Group Chats with file sharing like photos , videos etc) and how to implement the library. So looking forward for some sample on how to use SignalR with swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... I tried [adamhartford/SwiftR](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) and it worked for me. There is a great documentation available for using the library. hope this helps anyone searching the same. :)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. The installs needed to run the server side: SignalRApplication are vague:
(1) he said to run Mono 4.3 but latest is only 4.2 and
(2) DNX runtime: couldn't find it
(3) the link in running takes to white screen

I wish he had a video or proper links to make it easy to follow

Comment: @user1019042 Please open a SwiftR github issue if you're having trouble. The SignalRApplication and SignalRDemo repositories you see mentioned in the SwiftR readme are just example SignalR applications for demo purposes. They are not required to use SwiftR.

Comment: @Joker have you been able calling the signalR from a remote server using the swift!?

Comment: @user1019042 I have Started using SwiftR and I am able to call server methods using swift... and it's working quite normal...

Comment: Please note that SwiftR uses embedded web browser that uses SignalR JS libraries. This is not native sockets so it has limitation like no ability to set socket headers.

Comment: I am facing some issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942752/connection-error-in-signalr-in-swift-3-ios Can have any solution?